# Discard local commit history and replace it with origin's commit history

Tags: git

Let us assume my colleague and I are working on the same repository. We push and pull commits from a GitHub repo. Here is the timeline of events:

1. Both my colleague and I have the latest commit history in our repositories.
2. My colleague then performed `git commit --amend` to ammend the last commit in `master`. So he overwrote the commit history.
3. If there were multiple commits in the commit history and I perform `git pull` now it would try to merge his overwritten commit into my existing commit history.
4. If there was only one commit in the commit history and my colleague amended that lone commit, then it would create a totally unrelated commit history because the very earliest commit itself is different. If I perform `git pull` in this case, I would get this error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

What I want to do instead is discard my local commit history and replace it with the commit history on GitHub. I know I can `rm -rf .git` but then I have to perform a number of steps like `cd ..`, `rm -rf repo`, `git clone <repo-url>`. I am trying to script this thing and I am looking for the most straightforward way to bring my repository in sync with the `origin` even if it means discarding my local commit history.

Is there a `git` command that easily allows us to discard my local commit history and replace it with the `origin`'s commit history regardless of whether the two commit histories are related or unrelated?

Comment: you can try to rebase your current branch and then reset it to origin, then those changes will be updated in your local branch.

Comment: this is just a guess I am not sure this will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple command:

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Answer (score 2):

The two `git reset --hard` answers are correct, but it may help to examine *why* they are correct, and what they do.

Remember that in Git, a commit represents a complete snapshot of all files.  (Well, it's of all the committed files, but said that way it sounds silly, because now we're just saying "a commit contains the files that the commit contains".)  But it also has *metadata*, such as who made the commit (author name and email), when, and why (log message).  Each commit is uniquely identified by some big, ugly, apparently-random hash ID.  Moreover, one of the metadata items in each commit is the hash ID of the commit's *parent*.  This strings commits together, in a backwards-looking chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

"Commit history" is simply a commit, then its parent, then the next parent commit, and so on, all done backwards, following the chain of commit hash IDs from parent to parent.  We start at the end—in this case, at the commit with hash `H`.  That gets us the snapshot, but also the ID of commit `G`.  Then we move to `G`, which gets us the ID of `F`, which lets us continue moving backwards.  (Eventually we reach a commit with *no* parent—the first one ever made in that repository—which lets us stop.)

But: how do we know to start at `H` in the first place?  This is where *branch names* come in.  We have a name like `master`, and in that name, we store the hash ID of the *last* commit, in this case `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

When you run `git fetch`, you have your Git obtain commits from some other Git. Your names—`master`, `develop`, and so on—continue to record the hash IDs of your existing commits.  Your *remote-tracking names*—`origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on—record the hash IDs of *their* commits.

Although the hash IDs look random, they are not!  They are actually computed by doing a checksum over all the contents of each commit, including its parent commit hash.  So if our Git and their Git *started* with the *same* commit(s) (e.g., we cloned theirs originally), we'll share *some* set of commit hashes:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J    <-- master (HEAD)
```

When we pick up their *new* commits, their old commits (`A-B-...-H`) are still there, we just end up with a few more that we didn't have before:

```
             K--L   <-- origin/master
            /
A--B--...--H
            \
             I--J    <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now we have to do something to combine our commits with theirs.

If we don't *like* our commits, though, we can just throw ours out and use theirs.  That is, we can tell our Git: *stop looking at commit `J`, start looking at commit `L` instead.*  We have our Git rudely yank *our* `master` around so that it points to `L`, forgetting that we ever even *had* the `I-J` chain:

```
             K--L   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
            /
A--B--...--H
            \
             I--J    [abandoned]
```

We do this yanking-around with `git reset`.

For this particular case (where we want to wipe out our index and work-tree and replace them from the commit we're jumping to), we add `--hard`.

Git uses the special name `HEAD`, which is attached to our current branch `master`, to know which branch name to yank.  In this example there's only one branch name, so it's obvious, but when we add more branch names, `git reset` affects the one that has `HEAD` attached to it.

Note that Git does the same thing when we add *new* commits.  The new commit's parent is whichever commit `HEAD` points to—or more precisely, that the name that `HEAD` is attached-to points-to.  Then the name that `HEAD` is attached to, such as `master`, *moves!*  Git moves it to the new commit we just made, and now that's the last commit, from which we'll move backwards, one commit at a time, to find history.

If you and someone else both start with completely blank repositories, and you make a commit, you get:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and they get some other hash ID:

```
B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

When you `git fetch` from them, you get *their* commit too, and you set your name `origin/master` to remember their `master`, so now you have:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)

B   <-- origin/master
```

If you now `git reset --hard origin/master`, Git re-points the current branch name (`master`, to which `HEAD` is attached) so that it points to commit `B`, which you got from them, and to which your `origin/master` points, because your `origin/master` remembers what their Git told your Git when your Git called up their Git and asked for their latest commits.  So now you will have:

```
A   [abandoned]

B   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

If you wish to *keep* your `A`, you can simply set a name to remember it *before* you overwrite your current branch.  That is, while you still remember the actual hash ID of `A`, do:

```
git branch save <hash-ID>
```

or, as long as `master` still points to `A` (you haven't done the `git reset` yet):

```
git branch save master
```

and then you will have:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD), save

B   <-- origin/master
```

and then after `git reset --hard origin/master` you will have:

```
A   <-- save

B   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

The rules here are really simple:

- *Commits never change*.  Once made, they are frozen for all time.
- But we (humans) remember and find commits by *names*, and the name-to-hash-ID mapping in *branch names* like `master` *does* change.
- Git updates the current branch name (based on `HEAD`'s attachment) automatically when we make new commits.
- `git reset` changes the current branch name in an arbitrary way.

If you lose the *only* name for a commit, *and* it's not in some other name's history (so that you can't find it by the backwards-following process), Git will eventually—typically some time after 30 days or so—throw away the commit itself.  So abandoning a commit or chain of commits, as we can via `git reset`, can eventually have the frozen commit(s) destroyed.  (So if you want to save it/them, make sure you have some name for the *last* commit in the chain.)

This means *frozen for all time* in that first bullet-point is a bit of an exaggeration: it's *for as long as the commit itself exists*.  But, as with saying "a commit snapshot holds the files that the commit snapshot holds", it seems kind of tautological to say that.  Saying a commit is frozen forever isn't 100% correct, but it's close enough: it's frozen as long as the commit itself continues to exist.

Commits—as identified by hash IDs—are frozen, static, unchanging; *branch names* like `master` are fluid and constantly moving.  You move branch names however you like so to make the frozen commits *findable*.  You add *new* commits whenever you need to make some more history.  You yank the names rudely from where they are now to somewhere else when you want to try to *forget* some history.

The hash IDs are universal: they're the same in *every* Git repository, forever (well, every Git repository that ever shares with *this* Git repository).  The *branch names* are specific to this one particular Git repository!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option to do what you ask is to use `git reset --hard origin/master` to set your `HEAD` to `origin/master`.